# Inline-block elements expanding space below

Tags: html, layout, css

Creating a page layout using inline-block elements (vertically aligned to the top). The only issue, is that inline-block elements below another set of inline block elements will not fold into open space like floated elements do. It's almost as if it obeys row-like rules. Are there any fixes for this?

[Layout example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achimmer/BHpGZ/1/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:18px;
}
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:90vp;
}
.main_content {
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:76.04%;
    min-height:200px;
}
.content_details {
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:22.39%;
    margin-left:01.56%;
    min-height:250px;
}
.comments {
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:76.04%;
    min-height:150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main_content">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </div
    ><div class="content_details">
        <h2>Details</h2>
    </div
    ><div class="comments">
        <h2>Comments</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note I can change the mark-up to create only two inline-block elements (creating two columns), however I would like to know if there is a fix for 3 separate inline-block elements (like in the JSFiddle example), that way I wouldn't need to add extra mark-up.

Comment: And why are you using inline-block instead of floating div's?

Comment: -1 for inline block layouting. that technique needs to die. use floats.

Comment: Because floats are not intended for page layout and structure. Floats are supposed to be for wrapping text. Regardless let's not let this thread become bash battle for float vs. inline-block.

Comment: @user1721135 Why dont you just provide a workable solution with floats and explain why they are better instead of downvoting the question?

Comment: @Achimmer Are you saying inline block is intended to be used for layouting? Its not.

Comment: I will provide a workable solution as soon as I understand what the actual problem is. "table row rules" means little to me. Also vertical align only works on display table and display table-cell.

Comment: @user1721135 Would you like to suggest another alternative outside of floating and clearfixing? 

I'm trying to explore different options and make efficient page structure without extra markup.

Comment: Floating is the best. Clearing doesnt need extra markup. Pls state what you want exactly, and I may be able to help you. WTF is table row rules and open space? Pls be more specific, if you want to get an answer to your question.

Comment: @user1721135 Notice the space? (see the JSFiddle example)? The taller the blue section will get the larger that space between the green section and red section will get. I want to know if there is a fix for that without floating. If you don't have one nor are curious if there is one. You don't need to bother.

Comment: float wont help you with that either. You need to have 2 divs as columsn, or use something like masonry.js

Comment: @user1721135 Understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't.. Not like you are talking about. You'd have to use:

```
<div id="col1">
    <div id="maincontent"></div>
    <div id="comments"></div>
</div>
<div id="details"></div>
```

Then you would have `#col1` and `#details` as `inline-block` elements.

The whole point of an `inline-block` is that it is *inline* (i.e. on a line with other elements) it **isn't** acting like a table as you suggested, it's acting like a line of text (as it should) that is wider than it's container and breaking to the next line down.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GXmM6/ for a working example

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Oh for the record I wasn't saying it was acting like a table, but like a row, or as you said it: a line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Neither floats nor inline-block will do what you want there, unless you wrap each column in its own div. Short of that, there are JavaScript solutions for doing this, such as Masonry. (It involves a lot of positioning, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Did I get it right that you wanted the `.content_details` to be a sidebar? Then I just changed it from `display: inline-block` to `float: right` to place `.comments` seamlessly beneath your `.main-content`. See http://jsfiddle.net/koivo/7UqqF/ for working example. Think that even works just with `display: block` ...

```
* {
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: white; /* added */
    font-size: 18px;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90vp;
}
.main_content {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 76.04%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.content_details {
    background: blue;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    float: right; /* added */
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 22.39%;
    margin-left: 01.56%;
    min-height: 250px;
}
.comments {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 76.04%;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```